# Sumproduct equation alteration

Tags: excel

I am attempting to alter an Excel sumproduct equation with the intent of negating certain cells. The original equation reads:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B3:B25,--(AD3:AD25))
```

I altered the equation to now read:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B3,B4,B6,B8:B13,B16:B25),--(AD3,AD4,AD6,AD8:AD13,AD16:AD25))
```

As you can see, the array has been modified, so it is not a single range. While the first array is not a single range, Excel reads **(B3,B4,B6,B8:B13,B16:B25)**  as array1, but when following the calculation steps, I receive an error.

Does anyone have any recommendations, whether it is an alteration to the current equation, or using a different formula?

Thanks,

Comment: What is in the cells that are being skipped?  Show use the data.  It will help us help you.

Comment: As is, the only way is to sum 5 different SUMPRODUCTS()

Comment: Do you have anything in another column that would indicate which rows to include? If so you can reference the whole range from row 3 to 25 but only include the rows you need by referencing that other column, e.g.=SUMPRODUCT(B3:B25,AD3:AD25*(A3:A25="x"))

Comment: It's a bit clunky, but it looks like the 5 different SUMPRODUCTS() is the best choice. Thanks for the help.